# retry on some exceptions recursive

Tags: java

I have a method which uses proxies to retrieve information from a server. Sometimes due to a bad proxy I get `SocketException`, `SSLException`, `SSLHandshakeException` or `ConnectException`

I want the method to retry on the exceptions above, but on the IOException or no exception I want a string returned

Here is the method I constructed to test different scenarios

```
public String getTest(int i, int current, int total)
{
    String text = "";
    try
    {
        if (i == 1)
            throw new IOException();
        else if (i == 2)
            throw new SSLException("SSLEx");
        else if (i == 3)
            throw new SocketException();
        else
            text = "EVERYTHING GOOD";
    }
    catch (SSLException | SocketException re)
    {
        if (current < total)
        {
            System.out.println("Recalling " + current);
            getTest(1, ++current, total);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        text = "HTTP ERROR";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return text;
}
```

I call my test method by

```
System.out.println(c.getTest(3, 0, 5));
```

Initially the program would catch a `SocketException` then retry by passing 1 so I can emulate a working proxy but a server response with `IOException` as `i = 1` but the method never returns the text "HTTP ERROR"

What do I need to change in order for this to work as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to return the string returned by your recursive function call, you must place `return` before the recursive function call like so...

```
return getTest(1, ++current, total);
```

Right now you are simply running the recursive function and discarding its return value. Your logic then returns your `text` string from the initial call (which in the case of an `SSLException` looks like an empty string).

You could also accomplish the same effect by assigning `text` from the recursive function...

```
text = getTest(1, ++current, total);
```

Both statements, considering the rest of your logic, are equivalent.

Comment: I tried assigning text from the function http://pastebin.com/82GHJQBc and looks to be working now